Prove that the roots can't form a geometric progression

Let $P(x)$ be a cubic polynomial with integer coefficients and three positive irrational roots. Prove that the roots can't form a geometric progression.

Taking $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and the roots as $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, we get
Also, for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ to be in a geometric progression, $\sqrt{\alpha\gamma}=\beta$
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\dfrac{-b}{a}$$
$$\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha=\dfrac{c}{a}$$
$$\alpha\beta\gamma=\dfrac{-d}{a}$$
From these equations, we arrive at $\sqrt{\alpha\gamma}=\sqrt{\dfrac{-d}{a\beta}}$
Is my approach correct? How should I proceed? Detailed solutions an hints are welcome.

Sure...this isn't a crazy start. You haven't used the first two displayed equations yet, and it might make sense to write your three roots as $\alpha, t \alpha, t^2 \alpha$ instead (one fewer unknowns!). Keep fiddling around -- these are certainly the right things to be messing with.

You tagged "contest-math".  What is the source of this problem?  Is it a contest that is current?

$\beta$ such that $\beta^3 = -\dfrac{d}{a}$ is a root of the cubic. Show that this leads to a contradiction.

@RobertIsrael I believe it is from the St Petersberg Competition, but I can't find it online. Got it from a teacher.

As mentioned by @John Hughes in comments, assume three roots to be rational and take them as $\alpha,\alpha t, \alpha t^2 $ and rewrite those three equations:
\begin{align}
 \alpha(1+ t+t^2)&= \frac{-b}{a} \\
 \alpha ^ 2t(1+ t+t^2)&= \frac{c}{a} \\
 (\alpha t)^3&= \frac{-d}{a}
\end{align}
From eqns $1, 2$: $\alpha t = \frac{-c}{b}$. But from question, $\alpha t$ is irrational and $\frac{-c}{b}$ is rational which is a contradiction.

We have $\alpha \beta \gamma = \beta^3 = -\dfrac{d}{a}$ and $\beta$ is a root of the cubic
Substituting in the cubic we get $-d+b\beta^2+c \beta+d =0$ so that $\beta =0$ or $-\dfrac{c}{b}$ i.e. $\beta$ is rational.
